# ios: Timer working in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, timer

I am currently using a time on a Swift application. In previous app I had no problems but for this one I had a particular behavior: the timer works fine on the simulator but is never fired on the real device (10.0.2).

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target:self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.testTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
```

Here is the function called

```
func testTimer(){
  print("Timer called")
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this... I've tried to create this timer at various place with the same results....

EDIT:  I am currently in Swift 2.3

Comment: try on swift 3 `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: Selector((AppDelegate.testTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)`

Comment: it can be bug in ios 10.0.2. what's your simulator version?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**  this is only the case in Swift 3

I couldn't get your code to work on the simulator or the device, but it works on both like this

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:appDelegate, selector: #selector(appDelegate.testTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I am in Siwft 2.3, I am currently moving to 3.0 to see if there is an impact but not conviced that it's the root cause...